# Matlab m_map projection m_ll2xy units

Tags: matlab, map-projections

For projection I am using

```
m_proj('Mercator')
```

Next I use the following to convert an array of `lon` and `lat` points into `x y` coordinates.

```
[x,y] = m_ll2xy(lon,lat)
```

The `[x,y]` I got were in some units that I didn't understand. For example the `x` corresponding to longitude of -180 and 180 degrees are -pi and pi, while the `y` corresponding to latitude of -85 to 85 degrees are -3.1313 and 3.1313.

I want to get the `[x,y]` in units of km, which I understand have to be defined from a fixed point. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: I am not using this toolbox for geographical data, but from what I could find out about it you must specify the projection first eg, `m_proj('UTM','long',lon,'lat',lat);` for a mercator projection. This information can be retrieved for the documentation in M_Map. You sure must have read that, have you not? Otherwise you should read [this](http://www.eos.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html)

Comment: I have included    m_proj('Mercator') already. I have also read the documentation. In it they have provided a way of calculating the actual distance from projection coordinates, but only for areas close to the centre of the projection. But I want to calculate the actual distance for all points across the projection, not limited to the centre. Thanks.